# Can Zoo Tycoon 360 save/progress move to Xbox One?

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-one, zoo-tycoon-2013

I'm in the mood for a little Zoo Tycoon action on Xbox 360 right now, but won't have an Xbox One for another six months. If I get the 360 version, can I still move all my progress and saves to the Xbox One version, or would I have to start over?

It would be cool if I could transfer achievements, but that would be doubtful.

Comment: (The [zoo-tycoon] tag as it stands isn't right for this question, and making it a catch-all for both games doesn't seem right, but it won't let me create tags b/c low rep. If anyone could either fix the tag or make a new one, that'd be great. Thanks!)

Comment: Whats wrong with the Zoo Tycoon tag?

Comment: As it currently stands, [zoo-tycoon] is for questions about the 2001 PC game. Either a separate tag needs to be added for the 2013 Xbox game, or the tag needs to be edited to encompass both games. My gut says a second tag is the way to go, but I lack both knowledge of How Things Work™ here at Arqade and sufficient reputation to create the tag.

Comment: I think the tag wiki needs to be changed to compensate for all Zoo Tycoon games rather than creating a bunch of tags.

Comment: I created a [zoo-tycoon-2013] tag, which is in-line with how we handled other games here (i.e. sim-city). There are some differences in the two versions (X360 vs XBO) but since there's only these two questions about it for now, I don't think either justify a need for two tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There does not appear to be a transfer feature to convert an Xbox 360 Zoo Tycoon save file for use in the Xbox One version of Zoo Tycoon.

---

### Examples of Save File Transfer

We know that such a feature can be implemented, as it has for such games as [Destiny](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/184313/are-destiny-characters-backwards-and-or-cross-compatible), [Borderlands](http://www.gearboxsoftware.com/2015/03/cross-save-in-borderlands-the-handsome-collection-updated/) and [Grand Theft Auto V](https://support.rockstargames.com/hc/en-us/articles/202892778-Transferring-Your-Previous-Grand-Theft-Auto-Online-Characters-and-Progression-to-PlayStation-4-Xbox-One-or-PC). However, there are a few observant similarities in the games that do offer the feature.

1. **The feature is often advertised for player characters:** In situations where the player can transfer a save, they are not necessarily transferring all of their safe progress. Whenever I see the feature advertised, it is directly advertised to players wishing to continue completing the main story line on the new console; it is advertised for players wishing to continue playing their character on the new console.
2. **The feature is often advertised where the upgrade only improves performance:** In most cases, upgrading the game from an Xbox 360 version to an Xbox One version improves graphics and performance, but not much else. This might mean things are going on on the screen, but they are still the same things that occur in lower frequency, on the previous generation of console. Zoo Tycoon actually added a considerable amount of content, in the Xbox One version. There are 40+ new animals, and an entire online function. Some would consider the Xbox 360 Zoo Tycoon and the Xbox One Zoo Tycoon completely different games, in the same way that they are different from the PC version of Zoo Tycoon.
3. **The feature is often advertised to continue multiplayer features:** In most cases, safe file transfer is advertised in order for players to continue playing the same character, in a multiplayer environment. Zoo Tycoon, however, does not have a multiplayer feature. Or rather, it does, but only in the Xbox One version; you would not have a multiplayer save file if you were playing the game on Xbox 360.
   4 . **Save transferring is run through the developer:** in almost every situation, you have to complete the safe transfer process through the developer, externally. It is a process designed by the developers, and not really a feature that can be "turned on" for other Xbox 360 games, like it can be for backwards compatibility. This does nothing to explain why the feature is absent, but it means that if you think the feature **should** be implemented, you should probably direct your suggestions to the developer, [Frontier developments](http://www.frontier.co.uk/).

---

### The Future Prospects of Backwards Compatability

At the present time, the Xbox 360 version of Zoo Tycoon is not backwards compatible. If at any point it becomes compatible with the Xbox One, you can at least transfer your original Xbox 360 save files to your console, [through the cloud](http://support.xbox.com/en-AU/browse/xbox-360/games/Cloud%20storage). This save will not work on the Xbox One version, but might allow you to continue playing your older save, should an Xbox One be more accessible than the discontinued Xbox 360.

---

### Achievements

Achievements have always been tied to the version of the game, while progress is tied to the save file. There are separate achievement lists for the [Xbox 360 version of Zoo Tycoon](http://www.xboxachievements.com/game/zoo-tycoon/overview/) and [the Xbox One version of Zoo Tycoon](http://www.xboxachievements.com/game/zoo-tycoon-xbox-one/overview/), and they are subtly different. Even in the case of transferring saves, you will not be given the Xbox One version of the achievements you unlocked on Xbox 360.

You would still have your Xbox 360 achievements, but they would be listed under a separate Zoo Tycoon icon. You can also unlock the achievements, again, on the Xbox One version and both versions of the game will contribute to your overall gamerscore.