# Is cross-platform (not cross-generation) play possible in Destiny?

Tags: destiny

I know that cross-generation (PS3 player with a PS4 player) is not supported but can a XBOX One player play together with a PS4 player?

Comment: There is no game in which this is possible and there will likely never be one as Microsoft and Sony are direct competitors with their consoles. I can't see them working together to support cross-platform playing since they seem to rather try to seperate themselves with exclusives (even if it's just with some ingame stuff like in Destiny). Microsoft once tried cross-platform with Xbox-360 and PC with Shadowrun but it didn't work out well and they abandoned it soon after.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As far as I know, no it is not cross platform. Bungie stated it is due to 'fairness' as the consoles (/ pc if they added it) would all be slightly different in performances.

[Bungie Explains Why Destiny Cross-Platform Play Isn’t Happening](http://www.playstationlifestyle.net/2014/07/17/bungie-explains-why-destiny-cross-platform-play-isnt-happening/#/slide/1)

> Destiny won’t feature any sort of cross-platform play [...] This isn’t
>   due to a technical issue though, but rather Bungie not wanting to give
>   players on the new consoles an unfair advantage, as **Bungie Engineer
>   Roger Wolfson** told Digital Trends:
>
> > I’ll speak for the hypothetical player. I have a disadvantage sniping
> >     across the map because [my opponent with a new-gen console] is only
> >     two pixels on my screen and I’m four pixels on his. You see that in
> >     the world of PC gaming, where people are always racing to the best
> >     video card to give themselves the advantage.
> >
> > **Regardless of where the reality is**, there’s definitely a perception
> >     among gamers that better hardware means you have an advantage. We
> >     don’t want to have to enter that fray, so to create the best, most
> >     level playing field, both actually and perceptually, we separated it
> >     by platform.

The above is the reason given in the linked interview, by a Bungie engineer - though there are as stated in the below comments other reasons for why it is hard to cross platform a game in general. For example SONY and Microsofts platform policies / ability to work together.

Comment: Wish I would have seen this before yesterday.  Bought a new PS3 version of the game to play with my PS4 friends, only to find out that I wasted $60.  Thanks Best Buy and Bungie.  >.<

Comment: You can I believe migrate a PS3 character over to PS4 when you have one though? So play and if you get a PS4 you can use the character still :) See @Havatra 's post here http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/184317/73392

Comment: I know this already, but it doesn't help me in the short term.  I'm willing to pay $60 to play with friends.  I'm not willing to pay $450.  I guess I don't value my friends very much.  :P

Comment: @CrystalBlue in the short term true it doesn't help, you can always return the game and wait though if you don't want to play solo :)

Comment: They just don't want the people who play [not my console] to realize how much they suck compared to players of [my console] :)

Comment: I think the section you quoted applies to cross-generation, not cross-platform.  The reason you can't play between markets is due to Microsoft's policies on the matter.

Comment: If the target is 4px while viewed through a scope, it should probably have been culled by the renderer anyway. Further, ppi depends on the TV, not the console, and unless you're an aim-bot, ppi is more relevant to you than px. Finally, that example **is** a technical issue! (One that has a technical fix, even, but apparently the developers didn't want to fix it.) It's possible there are other issues about cross-platform "fairness" they couldn't or didn't have time to surmount, but if that's the case, you should use them as your example for explaining the imbalance, not 4-pixel opponents.

Comment: That edit was added and approved by other people than myself. That is just a quote from the interview not my own fact

Comment: It may be worth noting that Microsoft has an explicit no cross-platform policy in place for the XBox One, I am unable to provide a source but I know I've seen mention of it elsewhere on Arqade.

Comment: @Phaeze I believe their policy is to not share the server farm they'd provide, if developers have their very own server I don't think Microsoft can do much about it (technically speaking they can refuse, yes, but on what ground other than spite I can't imagine)

Comment: There would be a whole host of issues to contend with to support cross-platform gaming. Chat, friends lists, status updates, not to mention that games would need ensurances from both Sony and Microsoft that updates could go live at specified synchronized times to avoid having different versions on the two platforms. As much as I want this to happen, I know that it is unrealistic.

Comment: Cross platform generally means the devs have their own social system, pretty much like registering for yet another MMO. It's a lot of hassle, but since both SONY and Microsoft refuse to work together, that's the only alternative

Comment: These comments are getting too much really and should become a chat discussion instead, my post simply responds to the interview and the reason a Bungie engineer gave in said interview.

Comment: It seems to me that the quote from Bungie explains only why there is no cross-generation playing because of the disadvantage the old generation has. It doesn't address cross-platform playing in the same generation because the PS4 and XONE versions are virtually the same. But the question was specifically **not** about cross-generation.

Comment: I've unaccepted this answer for now. There is still no quote or fact that would clearly explain the rationale behind no cross-platform play. @Phaeze do you have a source for your claim?

Comment: @PatrickKlug I googled for 'Xbox one no cross platform' but I am at work and unable to review the content completely (its blocked) but in a couple of the snippets I'm getting the idea that that statement was strictly pc/xbox one directed. I can write up an answer later today where I can give some technical/business reasons why they could have avoided it (it won't be definitive).

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible, unfortunately. See [this post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/184313/are-destiny-characters-backwards-and-or-cross-compatible/184317#184317) for an earlier similar question. Here I explain that the servers are seperater for each console, but you can transfer your profile cross generation, but not cross system (Ex. from PS3 to PS4, but not PS3 to Xbox 360/One).

Answer (score 1):

This answer is entirely speculation, but as a software developer myself I feel it is educated speculation.

The biggest reason that I can come up with for Bungie (or any developer really) not to do this is that there is no framework in place for cross platform matchmaking, within each console the devs don't need to do much work (if any) to tap into a network of players for matchmaking. In order to implement a dedicated system to do so for the game would balloon both the cost of making the game and the time it takes to deliver the game (and keep in mind Destiny was already under development for more than 5 years and cost over $500 million).

Along side the lack of a shared network of players, they would also need to implement a custom friends system.

And the final reason that I can attribute to this goes along with their published reason for no cross generational play. These two systems are not exactly the same when it comes to hardware and although technically it won't make much of difference (if any) there are very many people that would use this difference as an excuse and flame the life out of Bungie.

Answer (score 0):

No. That is not supported in this game.